# Create table composed by multiple components

Tags: javascript, angular

So, as I started to dig in to angular2, I figured I create a table listing persons. One component for creating the table (`person-list`), and one for component for each person in the table (`person-list-item`).

Easy peezy, right? With the below output I realised it was not that easy. As you can see, the table rows are not following the table structure.

[image]

By viewing the html in the inspector we can also see that the `<person-list-item>` is ruining the table.

[image]

Is there a way to solve this problem, or should I just create the table rows in the `<person-list>` element in order to not let the browser ruin the table? I guess this is an issue that applies to other cases where multiple components would ruin a certain DOM element.

`app.component`

```
import {PersonListComponent} from './person-list.component';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

let template=`
<person-list></person-list>
`;

@Component({
    selector:'appz',
    template:template,
    providers:[PersonService],
    directives:[PersonListComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {
    public title;

    constructor(private _personService: PersonService) { 
        this.title=_personService.getPersons();
    }
}
```

`person-list.component`

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {PersonListItemComponent} from './person-list-item.component';
import {Person} from './person';

let template=`
    <h3>Persons</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <person-list-item 
                [firstName]="'John'"
                [lastName]="'Doe'"
                [age]='44'>
            </person-list-item>
            <person-list-item 
                [firstName]="'Foo'"
                [lastName]="'Bar'"
                [age]='34'>
            </person-list-item>
        </tbody>
    </table>
`;

@Component({
    selector:'person-list',
    template:template,
    directives:[PersonListItemComponent],
    inputs:['persons']
})
export class PersonListComponent {
    public persons: Person[];
};
```

`person-list-item.component`

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

let template=`
    <tr>
        <td>{{firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{age}}</td>            
    </tr>
`;

@Component({
    selector:'person-list-item',
    template: template,
    inputs:['firstName', 'lastName', 'age']
})

export class PersonListItemComponent {
    public firstName;
    public lastName;
    public age;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use an attribute or class selector instead of the tag selector for your component

for example `selector: 'tr[person-list-item]'` and use it like

```
<tr person-list-item>
```

or `selector: 'tr[personListItem]'` and `<tr personListItem>`

Alternatively you can use other ways to build a table.
For example like shown in https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart-patterns/blob/b3e8a306d05a9f3aae695a75ca5f4e3dccd64cf5/web/control_flow/using_template_repeat_with_a_table_row/my_element.html for a similar use case for Polymer where CSS is used to set `div` to behave like a `table`/`tr`/`td`

```
<style>
  .table {
    display: table;
  }
  .row {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .cell {
    display: table-cell;
  }
</style>
<div class="table">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fruits}}" as="fruit">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">{{fruit}}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: It does throw the follow exception: "Can't bind to 'firstName' since it isn't a known native property". Could you please provide the updated code for the component and/or link to a tutorial or similar that goes through this?

Comment: Either your selector doesn't match the tag you want to target, or you didn't pass a component to the `providers` argument of the parent components `@Component()` or `@View()` annotation.

Comment: Cheers, got it running.

Answer (score 1):

Unless PersonListItemComponent will someday be more complicated, I would dispense with that component and generate the rows in PersonListComponent using the `<template>` form of [NgFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html), which allows for multiple elements to be repeated.

**Note**: as Günter Zöchbauer mentions in the comments below, some browsers currently do not support `<template>` elements inside `<table>` elements.  So this approach may be a bit premature.

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'person-list',
  template: `
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <template ngFor #person [ngForOf]="people">
          <tr>
            <td>{{person.name}}
            <td>{{person.age}}
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `,
  styles: ['td { border: 1px solid gray } ']
})
export class PersonListComponent {
  @Input() people;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<person-list [people]="people"></person-list>`,
  directives: [PersonListComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  people = [ { name: 'Mark', age: "over 40" }, {name: 'cbass', age: "24?" }];
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
}
```

<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EJuJBbRFN0MDJNfy47zB?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: `<template>` has the disadvantage that some browsers drop it inside a `<table>`. Does Angular2 handle this in a special way so that this isn't an issue?

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, I was not aware of this issue, and I don't know if Angular 2 does anything special to avoid the issue.

Comment: The workaround from my answer using `display: table-xxx` comes from Polymer because IE (don't know which versions but I think recent ones still and probably Safari) ignore all disallowed tags including `<template>` even though according to recent W3C standards `<template>` should be allowed. So your approach should work eventually on all browsers, but currently you might run into issues.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, indeed, my Plunker doesn't work in IE11.  I'll update the answer.